# Button to Reload form in Access for OnLoad Event

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm working with two forms in an Access DB.
Form A: contains an OnLoad event that disables a button if a field does not contain data.
Form B: Is a data entry form that; when clicked, creates a new record in a joined table and fills in said field on Form A.

Form B: has a "Save" button that saves the data to the table, but also needs to reload Form A so it re-runs the OnLoad event and re-enables the button.

I've tried both:

```
Forms![Form A].Requery
```

And

```
Forms![Form A].Refresh
```

But neither of them reload the OnLoad event.
Is there another command I can call, or a different event I can use instead?
Thanks

Comment: Why not just renable the FormA button from your FormB code? `Forms![Form A].btnName.Enabled = True`

Comment: I...Never thought about that, and not sure why. Thanks for pointing out the obvious for me lol

Comment: No problem. Good luck and enjoy your coding experience